# U and PV changes in thermofluid processes

Tags: thermodynamics

If we have a steady flow open system, how can we know the change in U and PV? I mean if we input work in the system, how can we know that the work goes to U increase or PV increase? Also, can you give me a table of the possible processes (ie. adiabatic expansion) and their effect on U and PV?

Answer (score 0):

U is a property that can be calculated for 'ideal gases' only. For every other fluid, change in U can be calculated. But the physical properties, P and T can always be measured using pressure guages and thermometers etc. Enthalpy change could be calculated using the heat supplied and the heat rejected. Hence the change in U could also be calculated using $\Delta$H = $\Delta$U + $\Delta$(PV).

Answer (score 0):

The work can completely go to internal energy. For example, if you stir fluid in a fixed volume. The work can also completely go to PV. For example, if you very slowly blow a balloon. So with limited information, one cannot determine how much goes where. For ideal gas, it may be simpler, but you still need fluid dynamic computation to get change in P, V and T. Based on time history of P, V and T, you can then calculate how much change in PV and U.